# Python - Dot product for matrices doesn't seem to work when using sympy and lambdify

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, lambdify

I'm implementing a data processing flow in python. I'm trying to use symbolic calculations (`sympy` and `numpy`) as much as possible to have clear documentation consistent with the code. So when I try to get dot product and use it for real matrices (by means of `lambdify`) I get something else:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
init_printing()

A = Matrix([[1, 2], [1, 100]])
B = Matrix([[3, 4], [10, 1000]])
AA = MatrixSymbol('A',2,2)
BB = MatrixSymbol('B',2,2)
mulab = lambdify([AA,BB],AA*BB)
print(mulab(A,B))
print(A*B)
```

gives

```
[7, 1010, 406, 100020]
Matrix([[23, 2004], [1003, 100004]])
```

[Link to the live version of code](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/6de05f92-6996-4591-ad15-54ecb1561cb0/?i=true)

Did anybody face similar issues? Are there workarounds known?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `mulab(np.array([[1,2],[1,100]]), np.array([[3,4],[10,1000]]))` works.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lambdify` creates a function that should be used on NumPy arrays. If you pass a SymPy object to this function, the resulting behavior is undefined. If you want to evaluate SymPy expressions on SymPy expressions, just use the SymPy expression, using `subs` to replace the expression.

```
>>> (AA*BB).subs({AA: A, BB: B}).doit()
⎡ 23    2004 ⎤
⎢            ⎥
⎣1003  100004⎦
```

If you have NumPy arrays, that is when you want to use lambdify:

```
>>> mulab(np.array([[1,2],[1,100]]), np.array([[3,4],[10,1000]]))
 [[    23   2004]
 [  1003 100004]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It wasn't obvious for me that functions created with `lambdify` must accept NumPy arrays. I would think it can cast arguments internally if needed.